# Asymptotics for ODE with no closed form solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I have the ODE
$$ x'(t) = C\cdot t + D\cdot \sqrt{x(t)}$$

with $x(0) = 0$.

This doesn't have a closed form solution for generic constants $C,D\in \mathbb R$, but I am more interested in the growth behavior of $x$ for $t\to\infty$.

It makes sense that something quadratically growing will work, as $x'$ will be linearly growing and all terms on the right hand side do, too. But how can I do this properly? A reference to a book or paper would be highly appreciated.

So far, I have done the following: Make the ansatz $x'(t) = Et + F$ or $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}Et^2 + Ft$ (because $x(0) = 0$, we don't get another constant).

Then we get

$$Et + F = Ct + D\cdot \sqrt{E/2\cdot t^2 + Ft}.$$

Setting $t=0$ results in $F=0$ and we get only factors of $t$, hence
$$E = C + D\cdot \sqrt{E/2}$$
or
$$E = \frac{D^2 + 4C + \sqrt{D^4+8CD}}{4}.$$
Of course, this is all very rough and totally wrong but seems to recover some kind of asymptotic behaviour of $x$. I am interested in the correct way of doing that.

Comment: You can actually find a solution satisfying your initial conditions. It is $x(t)=(At)^{2}$ with $2A^{2}-DA-C=0$

Comment: @KirylPesotski:  Good catch.  Note that for this to hold, $A$ must be positive (more accurately, $\sqrt{A^2} = A$), so it's possible that one, both, or neither of the roots of that quadratic correspond to valid solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this formally, expand $x(t)$ in a "power series at infinity", multiplied by an unknown power of $t$:
$$
x(t) = t^\alpha \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{t^n}.
$$
We can assume WLOG that $a_0 \neq 0$, since if $a_0 = 0$  we could just rewrite this series with a lower power of $t$ in front and the new leading-order coefficient $a_0 \neq 0$.  We then have
$$
x'(t) = t^{\alpha} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\alpha - n) a_n}{t^{n+1}}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{x(t)} = t^{\alpha/2} \sqrt{a_0} \left[ 1 + \frac{a_1}{2a_0} t^{-1} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{4a_0^2}\right) t^{-2} + \dots \right] 
$$
This latter expression can be derived by expanding the power series $\sqrt{1 + x}$, where $x = \frac{1}{a_0} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n t^{-n}$.  It is straightforward, if tedious, to calculate it to any order.

Once we have these series in place, we can examine the possible asymptotic behavior.  We have
\begin{multline}
\alpha a_0 t^{\alpha-1} + (\alpha - 1) a_1 t^{\alpha - 2} + (\alpha - 2) a_2 t^{\alpha - 3} + \dots\\
 - C t - D \left[ \sqrt{a_0} t^{\alpha/2} + \frac{a_1}{2 \sqrt{a_0} }t^{\alpha/2 - 1} + \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{4a_0^2}\right) t^{\alpha/2-2} + \dots \right] = 0.
\end{multline}

The idea now is to ensure that these expressions vanish to all orders present in this big, messy series.  If $\alpha \neq 0$, the leading-order power present is either $t^{\alpha - 1}$, $t^1$, or $t^{\alpha/2}$.  If any one of these is greater than the other two, then there will be a large power in this series as $t \to \infty$ that dominates all of the other terms, and the series will not vanish.  Thus, at least two of $\alpha - 1$, $\alpha/2$, and $1$ must be equal—but as it happens, if two of them are equal, so is the third, with $\alpha = 2$.  Thus, we can rewrite this whole mess (in this case) as
\begin{multline}
(2 a_0 - C - D \sqrt{a_0} ) t^{1} +  \left(a_1 - D \frac{a_1}{2 \sqrt{a_0} }\right)t^{0} + \left[ - D \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{4a_0^2}\right) \right] t^{-1} + \dots = 0
\end{multline}
This implies that
$$
2 a_0 - D \sqrt{a_0} - C = 0 \\
a_1 \left( 1 - \frac{D}{2 \sqrt{a_0}} \right) = 0 \\
D \left(\frac{a_2}{a_0} - \frac{a_1^2}{4a_0^2}\right) = 0 \\
\vdots
$$
where we could carry this to higher order if desired.  These equations can be solved to determine the unknown coefficients $a_0$, $a_1$, and $a_2$.

Note finally that the case $\alpha = 0$ doesn't actually work:  in the original expanded power series, if $\alpha = 0$ then the leading-order power will be $t^1$ with coefficient $C$.  So unless $C = 0$, there will be a non-vanishing term in the asymptotic expansion.

---

**EDIT:** This whole procedure turns out to be overkill in this particular case, since as was pointed out by Kiryl Pesotski in the comments we have $x(t) = A^2 t^2$ is a solution, where $A$ is a positive root (if any) of the quadratic $2 A^2 - DA - C = 0$.  This is exactly the quadratic satisfied by $\sqrt{a_0}$ in my solution above, which implies that all of the higher-order coefficients $\{ a_1, a_2, \dots \}$ will vanish.  Still it's a useful technique for more general ODEs where there really isn't a closed-form solution.

Comment: This is really helpful (because I actually have a slightly more complicated ODE where I will need the general approach you presented). Only one thing: I got the term $\frac{a_2}{2a_0}-\frac{a_1^2}{8a_0^2}$ in front of the $t^{-2}$ contribution (and later it gets multiplied by an additional term of $\sqrt{a_0}$).

Comment: OK, so just one more follow-up: I am actually more interested in $x'(t) = C\cdot t + D\cdot \sqrt{x(t) \cdot  \log \log (x(t))}$. So I need to use the Taylor expansion of $\log\log(x)$. But this series has only a very small domain of convergence (and this means I can't really look at its behaviour for $t\to\infty$). How do I proceed in this case?

Comment: @MercuryBench:  For that ODE, I honestly don't know;  my impression is that is a much harder question than the one you posted.  It seems likely that you'll have $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$, but I don't think a series expansion of $\log \log x$ even exists about the point $x = \infty$ (which is what you would need.)  You might consider asking a new question concerning this new equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but a comment which is too long to be put in the comments section.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ct+D\sqrt{x(t)} \tag 1$$
What makes you think that it cannot be analytically solved ?

Let $x(t)=y(t)^2\quad\implies\quad 2y\frac{dy}{dt}=Ct+Dy$

Let $y(t)=tu(t)\quad\implies\quad 2tu(u+t\frac{du}{dt})=Ct+Dtu$
$$2u(u+t\frac{du}{dt})=C+Du\quad\implies\quad \frac{du}{dt}=\frac{C+Du-2u^2}{2tu}$$
$$\int \frac{dt}{t}=\int \frac{2udu}{C+Du-2u^2}$$
$$ \ln|t|=-\frac{D}{\sqrt{-8C-D^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4u-D}{\sqrt{-8C-D^2}}\right)-\frac12\ln|2u^2-Du-C|+\text{constant}$$

Leading to the analytic solution expressed on parametric form (with parameter $u$) :
$$\begin{cases}
t=c_1\frac{1}{\sqrt{2u^2-Du-C}}\exp\left(-\frac{D}{\sqrt{-8C-D^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4u-D}{\sqrt{-8C-D^2}}\right)\right)\\
x=c_1^2\frac{u^2}{2u^2-Du-C}\exp\left(-\frac{2D}{\sqrt{-8C-D^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4u-D}{-8C-D^2}\right)\right)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for going through the calculation for me! I don't quite understand your comment about the trivial solution, though: For $t>0$, we have $x'(t) > 0$ (at least for $C,D > 0$), so how can $x(t) = 0$ be a solution?

Comment: But for $t>0$, the right hand side of the ODE is $C\cdot t + D\cdot \sqrt{x(t)} > 0$, so $x'$ needs to match this, right?

Comment: My mistake! Obviously you are right. I delete my note at the end of the answer.